# Convert RewriteRule to nginx to map htm file to php file

Tags: nginx

How do I convert the following Apache rule to something I can use in my nginx conf file?

```
RewriteRule   ^/somefolder/somepage.htm   /somefolder/somepage.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple with nginx:

Put this anywhere in the *sever* section:

```
rewrite ^/somefolde/somepage.htm /somefolder/somepage.php last;
```